# What's the best way to perform an async.series with a timeout on each iteration?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, settimeout

I need to wait a second between iterations of an `async.eachSeries` call owing to the limitations of a third party API which protects against abuse by restricting the caller from making more than one request per second.

I'm not entirely clear on how to do this.  Can I simply pass the series `callback` as the parameter function to a call to `setTimeout`? I suspect this won't work but thought I'd ask before I assemble all the code necessary to test it out.  If `setTimeout` is not the answer, then what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, `setTimeout()` can be used to add a delay where the `callback()` is normally called.

```
// vs. callback();
setTimeout(callback, 1000);
```

Any arguments that would be passed to the `callback()` can be [passed after the timeout's `delay`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_arg).

```
// vs. callback(err);
setTimeout(callback, 1000, err);

// vs. callback(err, result);
setTimeout(callback, 1000, err, result);
```

Example:

```
async.eachSeries([1, 2, 3], function (n, callback) {
    request3rdPartyAPI(n, function (err, result) {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000, err);
    });
});
```

Comment: cool... I figured it would either be exactly this easy or some really awful closure hack.  I'm glad it's the former :-)